# How to Sum Specific Sub Groups Inside a Group in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

The situation is, I want to create a report which shows me the total amount I get in a specific date. So I grouped my report by TransactionType Field.

TransactionType (Either `Sale` or `Sale Return`). So My Report Looks Like this.

**Amount**

**Sale**
               100

               200

               400

Sum       **700**

**Sale Return**
               100

               200

Sum       **300**

So I want to Subtract `Sale Return` from `Sale` in report footer. Like 700 - 300 = 400.

To achieve this I need to get Sum of Each Sub Group (Sale and Sale Return). But I am unable to do that because Group is same. I tried using `RunningTotalField` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

create a formula called Val_Returned with an expression such as:
IF TransactionType = "Sale" Then {Amount} ELSE 0
Then, simply sum it to get the total Sale Amount.

Repeat with similar logic to get Returned amount.